# Java inner class null pointer exception

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, pointers, null

The code for a chat client I'm working on generates the following error:

```
"Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException at ChatClient$FieldLengthChecker.run(ChatClient.java:26)"
```

This error only occurs about 50% of the time.
The other 50% of the time, the program acts as intended.

The thread is used to "listen" for characters in the userAuthField to ensure that the user enters at least 4 characters before I set authLoginButton.setEnabled(true).

The button should be disabled if the length of the authUserField content falls below 4 characters.

If I run the program and enter 4 characters into the field, it either gives me the exception I listed above or runs fine until I close the application (As in, I can add and remove characters and the button will activate/deactivate as intended until I close the program).

Any and all insight is greatly appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ChatClient {
    JFrame authFrame;
    JPanel authPanel;
    JLabel authUserLabel;
    JLabel authPassLabel;
    JLabel authMessageLabel;
    JTextField authUserField;
    JTextField authPassField;
    JButton authLoginButton;
    JButton authRegisterButton;

    String authUserData;
    String authPassData;

    //This inner-class is used in a thread to listen
    //for characters entering and exiting the userAuthField
    //in order to change the status of authLoginButton
    public class FieldLengthChecker extends Thread {

        public void run() {
            while(true) {
               String username = authUserField.getText();
               if (username.length() > 3) {
                   authLoginButton.setEnabled(true);
                }
                else {
                     authLoginButton.setEnabled(
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChatClient chat = new ChatClient();
        chat.start();
    }

    public void start() {
        FieldLengthChecker FieldLengthChecker = new FieldLengthChecker();
        authFrame = new JFrame("Authentication");
        authFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        authPanel = new JPanel();
        authUserLabel = new JLabel("Username");
        authPassLabel = new JLabel("Password");
        authMessageLabel = new JLabel();
        authUserField = new JTextField(20);
        authPassField = new JTextField(20);
        authLoginButton = new JButton("Login");
        authLoginButton.addActionListener(new AuthLoginButtonListener());
        authLoginButton.setEnabled(false);
        authRegisterButton = new JButton("Register");
        authFrame.getContentPane().add(authPanel);
        authPanel.add(authUserLabel);
        authPanel.add(authUserField);
        authPanel.add(authPassLabel);
        authPanel.add(authPassField);
        authPanel.add(authLoginButton);
        authPanel.add(authMessageLabel);
        authFrame.setSize(250, 300);
        authFrame.setVisible(true);
        FieldLengthChecker.start();
    }

    //This inner-class takes the user and pass information from
    //authUserField and authPassField and sends it to the 
    //Authentication server to query the associated database
    class AuthLoginButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        Socket authSock;
        BufferedReader authReader;
        PrintWriter authWriter;
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            try {
                authSock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5001);
                InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(authSock.getInputStream());
                authReader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
                authWriter = new PrintWriter(authSock.getOutputStream());
                System.out.println("Connection established with Authentication server");

                authUserData = authUserField.getText();
                authPassData = authPassField.getText();

                authWriter.println(authUserData + " " + authPassData);
                authWriter.close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println();                                                   
                System.out.println("Failed to establish a connection with the authentication server.");
                System.out.println("See above stack trace for further information.");
                authFrame.dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? Or have you added println() to potentially problematic places piecemeal?

Comment: I did earlier, but I took it out to make it more reader friendly for stackoverflow users. I placed several println() entries in it acting as 'breaks' to no avail either. I am interested in knowing of a good Java debugger though. As an amateur, I assumed I should be manually debugging everything as to get a better understanding of how Java works.

Comment: So where is line 26??

Comment: This is line 26:
 if (username.length() > 3) {

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try something like this?

```
public class FieldLengthChecker extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        while(true) {
           try {
                String username = authUserField.getText();
                if (username.length() > 3) {
                    authLoginButton.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    authLoginButton.setEnabled(false);
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                // handle exception
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent RaidZero. Works like a charm. For now, just dumping the exception into nothingness appears to be acceptable, as I tested this about 40 times now and it runs as intended. Thank you!

Comment: Why not just check username for null, rather than catching the exception??

Comment: I did not realize what was causing the exception in the first place or I would have implemented that. I am still a beginner, really. I'm still learning elementary things about the language day by day.